# Why doesn't this short bash script/function work? Possible solutions? (UNIX bash scripting)

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, scripting, sh

I am trying to make an error message appear if someone runs my script but a file which doesn't exist is entered as an argument.

```
function finder(){
if test find $1 ; then
 exit 0
 else
 exit 1
fi
}

#### error message if file does not exist

if test finder -eq 1 ; then
 echo "safe_rm: cannot remove '$1' : No such file or directory"
fi
```

I get an error message saying an integer is expected from the finger function - but it shouldn't it produce an exit status of 0 or 1 according to my function?

how do I make an if statement that says "If the exist status of finder is 1, then echo "No such file or directory exists"?

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not **if [ -d /path/to/folder ]** or **if [ -f /path/to/file ]**

Answer (score 3):

Several problems:

1. `exit` stops the script. To return a value from a function, use `return`.
2. `test` does not take a command as its first argument. See `man test` for details.
3. `finder -eq 1` does not run `finder`, it takes it as a string.

What you really meant was something like

```
if test -e "$1" ; then
    # ...
else
    echo "$1 does not exists."
fi
```

Comment: +1, but should mention that if the function is retained, `if test finder -eq 1` should rewritten `if finder "$1"; then ...` in order to invoke it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use:

```
if [ ! -e $1 ] ; then
    echo "safe_rm: cannot remove '$1' : No such file or directory"
fi
```